# How do I trigger javascript to execute on document windown resize (without refreshing the page)?

Tags: javascript, css, triggers, resize, execute

I'm having a problem getting javascript to execute whenever I resize the browser window. I am using the following javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var heightNum = $('#work-details-info').height() + 39;
    if (($(document).width() > 767) && ($(document).width() < 900)) { 
    $('#work-details-left-cntr').css("height", (heightNum));
    }
});
```

It's calculating the height of a specific div. Then it is adding 39px to that height, and it sets the new height to another div. This works perfectly whenever I resize the page and then press refresh/reload. However, I want this to trigger without having to refresh/reload. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
  var heightNum = $('#work-details-info').height() + 39;
  if (($(document).width() > 767) && ($(document).width() < 900)) { 
    $('#work-details-left-cntr').css("height", (heightNum));
  }
});
```